# Django template won't display my model variants

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

Sorry I'm new to Django and programming in general but I'm trying to call on variables from my model to be displayed on a specific page.  I mapped my URLs to example.com/archive/book_slug and would like the details like title, author, ISBN, or whatever.  I used the blog app to register my models in the admin page.

The problem occurs in my template when I go to the URL nothing gets displayed.  I want the title of the book to appear in the header.  Can anyone help please?

blog/models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Book_item(models.Model):
   book_title = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False)
   book_author = models.CharField(max_length=255)   
   book_publisher = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
   book_date_published = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
   book_isbn = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
   book_slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True, blank=False,
                                primary_key=True)
   book_body = models.TextField(blank=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.book_title
```

blog/views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from blog.models import Book_item

# view for /achive/; template at archive.html
def archive_index(request):
    book_info = Book_item.objects.all()
    context = {'book_info' : book_info} 
    return render(request, 'blog/archive.html', context)

# view for /archive/book_title; 404 if no title; template at book_detail.html
def book_details(request, book_slug):
    bookdeets = Book_item.objects.filter(book_slug=book_slug)
    details = get_object_or_404(Book_item, book_slug=book_slug)
    context = {'details' : details, 'bookdeets' : bookdeets}
    return render(request, 'blog/book_detail.html', context)
```

blog/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from blog import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',

    # archive index at /archive/                   
    url(r'^$', views.archive_index),

    # book deatils at /archive/book_title
    url(r'^(?P<book_slug>[\w-]+)/$', views.book_details),

 )
```

blog/book_detail.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block title %}{{Book_item.book_title}}{% endblock %}

{% block headercontent %}
<h1>{{Book_item.book_title}}</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What are the contents of `base.html`? Does it define a block called `headercontent`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try;

```
<h1>{{details.book_title}}</h1>
```

You've passed the book details to the template via the "details" variable in response context.

As an aside, you can actually also remove the `bookdeets = Book_item.objects.filter(book_slug=book_slug)` line as you are already getting book you want directly through the get_object_or_404 method underneath. Given the slug is unique the `filter` will just return a single element queryset, so these are just two different ways to get the same object (except get_object_or_404 is a handy 'shortcut' that will return a 404 if nothing is found).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you're retrieving both a queryset of the matching `Book_item` and the instance itself. Usually you'd do one or the other.

Comment: It's not quite true that the two expressions return the same object - as you say, `filter` returns a queryset, while `get_object_or_404` returns a model instance. If you tried to deference `bookdeets.book_title` you'd get an exception.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper You're right, I wasn't trying to say they were the same as such, I've made somewhat of a hash of my explanation!

Comment: Great it worked.  Thanks a lot.  I also thought the bookdeets was a bit repetitive so I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

try using your model name in lower case.

```
<h1>{{ book_item.book_title }}</h1>
```